# How can I remove div have id or attributes by HTML Purifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I have a content like

```
<div class="block-related" data-component-type="link" id="block-related-link">
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="block-related" data-component-type="topic" id="block-related-topic">
    <ul>
        <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I remove div by using HTML Prurifier (fitler by id or attribute data-component-type)

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks !!!!

Comment: Do you want to the ul tags to say, or everything inside the divs to be removed? Do you want to remove all divs or only ones with certain ids or classes?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/VdCtq/

```
$('#rm_id').click(function () {
    $('#block-related-link').remove();
});

$('#rm_attr').click(function () {
    $('div[data-component-type="topic"]').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but not my mean. I had that content from "form submit action" (CKEditor), and I want remove it by HTML Puriffier.